# Django Migrations Issue. makemigrations ignoring some fields in model file

Tags: django, django-models, migration, models, makemigrations

THIS IS MY MODEL FILE

```
from django.db import models
class Donor(models.Model):
   Donor_name = models.CharField(max_length=150),
   Donor_status = models.IntegerField(),
   Donor_city = models.CharField(max_length=50),
   Donor_group = models.CharField(max_length=10),
   Donor_phone = models.CharField(max_length=12),
   Donor_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
```

THIS IS MY MIGRATION

## Generated by Django 2.0.2 on 2018-03-30 09:19

from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Donor',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
    )
```

Why are other fields ignored ?
using Django version 2 with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

The commas at the end of the lines cause Python to treat them as tuples. Remove them.

```
class Donor(models.Model):
   Donor_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
   Donor_status = models.IntegerField()
   Donor_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   Donor_group = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   Donor_phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
   Donor_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
```

Once you have made this change, you can run `makemigrations` again and Django should include your new fields. If you haven't run the migration that creates the modlel yet, you could remove the migration file before doing this. You can use `python manage.py showmigrations` to check whether the migration has already been run.

Note that in Django, the recommendation is to use lowercase_with_underscores for your field names, e.g. `donor_name` and `donor_status`.